# I cant send email with django

Tags: python, django

When I try to send an email with django this error appears: smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials b2sm12936529wrm.30 - gsmtp')

Comment: As the error says, your credentials are invalid...

Answer (score 1):

If your credentials are correct and you're still facing this issue, first make sure that you've allowed less secure applications to access your mail. To do this visit https://accounts.google.com and search for less secure apps. You can enable it from there.

If this error still persists, follow the link in your question and in the step 2, there's link called /DisplayUnlockCaptcha, it will deactivate and reactivate your account.

This happens when google doesn't trust the source. This is only a temporary solution, chances are you'll run into this again. So stop using personal mail for dev purpose and get a gsuite account or any other business mail like twilio send grid